# How can I use values read from TFRecords as arguments to tf.reshape?

Tags: python, tensorflow

```py
def read_and_decode(filename_queue):
  reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
  _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
  features = tf.parse_single_example(
      serialized_example,
      # Defaults are not specified since both keys are required.
      features={
          'image_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
          'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
          'height': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
          'width': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
          'depth': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)
      })
  # height = tf.cast(features['height'],tf.int32)
  image = tf.decode_raw(features['image_raw'], tf.uint8)
  image = tf.reshape(image,[32, 32, 3])
  image = tf.cast(image,tf.float32)
  label = tf.cast(features['label'], tf.int32)
  return image, label
```

I'm using a TFRecord to store all my data. The function read_and_decode is from the TFRecords example provided by TensorFlow. Currently I reshape by having predefined values:

```py
image = tf.reshape(image,[32, 32, 3])
```

However, the data that I will be using now is of different dimensions. For example, I could have an image that is [40, 30, 3] (scaling this is not an option as I don't want it to be warped). I would like to read in data of different dimensions and use random_crop in the data augmentation stage to circumvent this problem. What I need is something like the following.

```py
height = tf.cast(features['height'], tf.int32)
width = tf.cast(features['width'], tf.int32)
image = tf.reshape(image,[height, width, 3])
```

However, I can't seem to find a way to do this. Thanks for your help!

EDIT:

```
ValueError: All shapes must be fully defined: [TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(None), Dimension(None)]), TensorShape([])]

image = tf.reshape(image, tf.pack([height, width, 3]))
image = tf.reshape(image, [32,32,3])
```

The problem is definitely with these 2 lines. The hard coded variables work, but not the one with tf.pack().

Comment: Re: the edit. It looks like you're using one of the image ops that requires all shapes to be known at graph construction time (like the crop or pad ones). However, this seems unrelated to the original question (about reading things out of TFRecords) so you should make a new question about how to deal with this. Make sure to include a full stack trace with the error message!

Comment: @mrry, you're right that it's tf.random_crop that's causing this issue. As per your suggestion, I have asked a new question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35691102/valueerror-all-shapes-must-be-fully-defined-issue-due-to-commenting-out-tf-ran.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're very close to having a working solution! Right now there's no *automatic* way to give TensorFlow a list made up of tensors and numbers and make a tensor from it, which [`tf.reshape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape) is expecting. The answer is to use [`tf.stack()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack), which explicitly takes a list of N-dimensional tensors (or things convertible to tensors) and packs them into an (N+1)-dimensional tensor.

This means you can write:

```
features = ...  # Parse from an example proto.
height = tf.cast(features['height'], tf.int32)
width = tf.cast(features['width'], tf.int32)

image = tf.reshape(image, tf.stack([height, width, 3]))
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix. It worked initially. But now I'm getting this error. Refer to edit for details.

Comment: I am also having same issue, since tf.pack is being removed and tf.stack is replaced with it, I used  tf.stack, But after hard cording   dimension everything worked. Is this the expected behavior of Tensorflow

Comment: I found how it works after reading your answer in here[https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2604], Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same issue. According to the [Tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/shuffle_batch), you will be encountered this situation if you are trying to use shuffle_batch 
operation after reading required data.

Like in this example, if you don't use shuffle_batch processing, you can load dynamic dimensional files.

```
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
    features = tf.parse_single_example(
        serialized_example,
        features={
             'clip_height': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
             'clip_width': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
             'clip_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
             'clip_label_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)
        })
    image = tf.decode_raw(features['clip_raw'], tf.float64)
    label = tf.cast(features['clip_label_raw'], tf.int32)
    height = tf.cast(features['clip_height'], tf.int32)
    width = tf.cast(features['clip_width'], tf.int32)
    im_shape = tf.stack([height, width, -1])
    new_image = tf.reshape(image, im_shape )
```

But if you are to use shuffle batch processing, you can't use `tf.stack`. You have to define dimensions statically similar to this.

```
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
    features = tf.parse_single_example(
        serialized_example,
        features={
             'clip_height': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
             'clip_width': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
             'clip_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
             'clip_label_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)
        })
    image = tf.decode_raw(features['clip_raw'], tf.float64)
    label = tf.cast(features['clip_label_raw'], tf.int32)
    height = tf.cast(features['clip_height'], tf.int32)
    width = tf.cast(features['clip_width'], tf.int32)
    image = tf.reshape(image, [1, 512, 1])
    images, sparse_labels = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
            [image, label], batch_size=batch_size, num_threads=2,
            capacity=1000 + 3 * batch_size,
            min_after_dequeue=100)
```

@mrry please correct me if I am wrong.