# Using values read from TFRecords as arguments to tf.reshape

Tags: python, tensorflow

This question is related to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35620157/how-can-i-use-values-read-from-tfrecords-as-arguments-to-tf-reshape) and this [github discussion](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2604)

I'm using a TFRecord to store my data, the code works if I hardcode the shape. However, I need to obtain the shape from the TFRecord.

```
def _parse_function(example_proto):
    keys_to_features = {'image_size': tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64),
                        'seq_steps': tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64),
                        'K': tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64),
                        'T': tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64),
                        'input_seq': tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string)}

    parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(example_proto, keys_to_features)

    image_size = tf.cast(parsed_features['image_size'],tf.int32)
    seq_steps = tf.cast(parsed_features['seq_steps'],tf.int32)
    K = tf.cast(parsed_features['K'],tf.int32)
    T = tf.cast(parsed_features['T'],tf.int32)

    input_shape = [image_size, image_size, seq_steps*(K+T), 2]

    input_seq = tf.reshape(tf.decode_raw(parsed_features['input_seq'], tf.float32), tf.stack(input_shape), name='reshape_input_seq')

    return input_seq
```

The returned tensor has dynamic shape and when going through the model tf.reshape is called at some point which then returns an error since the tensor shape is only partially known.

I'm not sure how to proceed. I tried fixing this by setting `input_seq.set_shape(tf.stack(input_shape))` before returning it.

This however gives me another error `TypeError: Tensor objects are not iterable when eager execution is not enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn.`

To fix this I tried `dataset = dataset.map(lambda elems: tf.map_fn(_parse_function, elems))` instead of just `dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)`

This then returns `ValueError: slice index 0 of dimension 0 out of bounds.`

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your inputs have a dynamic shape, so you're never going to be able to correctly set static shape information to anything other than `None` for the dimensions which can change. You might look into something like [`batch_sequences_with_states`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/training/batch_sequences_with_states) for converting different size sequences into rectangular arrays which can be dealt with efficiently.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into batch_sequences_with_states. So how is this problem usually solved? Do you use TFRecords assuming the data always has the same shape and thus can be set statically?

Comment: For sequences, `batch_sequences_with_states` is pretty standard. Some people do their own slicing (e.g. `tf.contrib.timeseries` does similar things). For images with varying dimensions, people often take random crops. So having variable sized records is fine, there just needs to be some step which rectangularizes things (assuming batching is necessary for performance; it's possible to just not batch things, of course).

Comment: Ah ok yes, makes sense. Thanks!